# How to set line height in Libre Office Calc

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have entered two lines in a wide enough cell. I used `CTRL`+`Return` combination at the end of the first line to wrap the text and entered the second line.

I was able to set different style for the two lines, however I could not find how to set the line-height, the space between the two lines.

How is it set?

Answer (score 2):

Writer has line spacing settings, but Calc does not.  *Format -> Spacing* and *Format -> Paragraph* are permanently disabled in Calc.

My suggested workaround is to insert an empty line and a space (`Ctrl`+`Enter`, `Space`).  Then select the space and change the font size.  Here is an example using font size 2 for the space, and normal size 10 text.

[image: spacing with font size 2]

This question was also asked at https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/31054/how-can-i-adjust-line-spacing-for-cells-with-word-wrap-in-calc/, where more ideas for workarounds are given.

Comment: Im currently using a 14pt for first line, and 12pt for second line, adding a 2pt line in between gives no results in my case. Using Google font Ek Mukta.

Answer (score 0):

The row height can be set by selecting the row (click on row number in left most column) and then right clicking to get a drop down menu that includes "Row height..." and "Optimal Row height...".  This is not as convenient as, for example, choosing a line spacing of 1.5x, but it does work.

Comment: That is not the line height that was being asked about.